# What approach to take when saving json locally on ios device?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

Currently my app pulls data from a custom api, parses it and saves the data to multiple arrays.

I am using AWS RDS to store all the data which is displayed on the api, and using AWS EC2 to host the file to access the api.

The problem I have ran into is that each download of the api is ~1mb and AWS charges $0.09/GB of data. I need to lower costs and so I can't have my app pulling the api data every time the refresh function is called. (my api updates every 4 hours. If users refresh the app before my api has updated, the refresh function will do nothing).

My current idea to solve this is either:

(1)download the json data onto the device, then parse & save the offline data to arrays

(2)or download and parse it into arrays, then save those arrays locally (from searching I believe I need to use NSKeyedArchiver or UserDefaults?)

I am not sure what the best approach to this is.

Comment: There are lots of options, store into a local database (core data, realm), store the actual JSON responses as files etc etc. I wouldn't recommend storing as files though.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I haven't heard of realm before but upon looking into it it seems to be perfect to solve my problem

Comment: Your welcome, yeah Realm is very good. I would recommend this option.